# Decompression of a string sent from c# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, mysql, apache, compression

This is the function which zip the string to be sent to php code

```
public string Zip(string value)
    {
        //Transform string into byte[]  
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
        int indexBA = 0;
        foreach (char item in value.ToCharArray())
        {
            byteArray[indexBA++] = (byte)item;
        }
        //Prepare for compress
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        System.IO.Compression.GZipStream sw = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms,
        System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
        //Compress
        sw.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        //Close, DO NOT FLUSH cause bytes will go missing...
        sw.Close();
        //Transform byte[] zip data to string
        byteArray = ms.ToArray();
        System.Text.StringBuilder sB = new System.Text.StringBuilder(byteArray.Length);
        foreach (byte item in byteArray)
        {
            sB.Append((char)item);
        }
        ms.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
        ms.Dispose();
        return sB.ToString();
    }
```

and am sending the request using

```
 string data = req.Zip(xml);
        string resp = req.post(url,"&Data="+data);
```

i tried to use gzuncompress , gzdecode but all produce  a data error any body knows why ?

Answer (score 2):

This code is bizarre to start with:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
int indexBA = 0;
foreach (char item in value.ToCharArray())
{
    byteArray[indexBA++] = (byte)item;
}
```

You're converting it to a byte array using UTF-8 encoding... and *then* you're overwriting the contents of that array (or at least *some* of the contents of that array) by casting each character to a byte - which is effectively applying ISO-Latin-1 encoding.

Then later on, you're converting *arbitrary binary data* to a string like this:

```
byteArray = ms.ToArray();
System.Text.StringBuilder sB = new System.Text.StringBuilder(byteArray.Length);
foreach (byte item in byteArray)
{
    sB.Append((char)item);
}
```

**Don't do that.** It's opaque binary data - the chances of the "string" you're creating (again, effectively created via ISO-8859-1) being properly transferable are very slim.

When encoding arbitrary binary data as a string, you should almost always use Base64:

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

You're then *also* using the data as URL-encoded form data - despite the fact that the string could quite easily include characters such as `&` and `%` which have special meaning within URL encoded text. Don't do that either.

Basically, you should:

- Choose which encoding you want to use for the initial text to binary conversion. UTF-8 is a good choice here, as it can represent all of Unicode.
- Perform the compression (and no, flushing should *not* cause problems here, although you should also close anyway - ideally via a `using` statement)
- Transform the binary data back into text (assuming you really have to) using base64. If you're going to use this as a URL parameter, you should use a web-safe variant of base64, as described on the [Wikipedia base64 page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

To decompress, you'll obviously need to perform the base64 to binary conversion before decompression.

If possible, it would be significantly more efficient (in terms of the transferred data) to post the compressed data *as binary data* rather than as a URL-encoded form parameter.

Comment: thanks john, but it's not my code i'll decompress the result in PHP.

do u mean to use:
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);instead of converting the char array into string ?

Comment: @user874557: Then there's no hope. The C# code you've presented is *extremely* likely to lose data. It **must** be changed.

Comment: am not good in c# very much so you may tell me how to compress a string data and also to be able to decompress it in PHP by gzuncompress or gzdecode cause i've tried all of them on a function that seems to lose data

Comment: does GzipStream add headers to the compressed data or it's like gzcompress?

Comment: @user874557: I don't expect it to add headers, but the main problems in the code you've presented aren't in the compression - they're in the conversion to and then from binary data.

Comment: how to convert it into binary data  and post them as a binary string ..i don't get it?

Comment: @user874557: Well, it depends on what your PHP code can handle. You can use `WebClient.UploadData` to upload the compressed binary data, but I don't know what code you'd use at the PHP side to fetch it. Using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)` is a good way of converting the original text data to binary - obviously to convert it *back* to text in PHP, you'll need to use whatever UTF-8 decoding facilities PHP provides.